How to setup test resources correctly to read them in a Scala-Cli project
I use munit and scala-cli in a small Scala 3 project
In a test I want to read a resource. Under the project root the resource is at the path:
src/test/resources/testResource.txt

The Scala file of the test to get the resource is at
src/test/scala/org/myorg/myproject/mypack/App.test.scala

And the file looks like this:
//> using test.dep org.scalameta::munit::1.0.0

package org.myorg.myproject.mypack.tests

import java.io.InputStream

class ResourceTests extends munit.FunSuite: 
  test("getResource"):
    val inp: InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/testResource.txt")
    assertNotEquals(inp, null)

When I run this test, the "getResource" test always fails.inp is always null, so the test does not find the resource.
I have tried to tell scala-cli that src/test/resources is a resource directory with
//> using test.resourceDir src/test/resources 

but the test results stay the same.
So, how can I correct this? Do I have to put the resource somewhere else?

Have you tried "/testResource.txt" -> "testResource.txt" (no /)?

@MateuszKubuszok Yes, I tried both versions - with the same result.
